# PyTelegramBotApi: Как отправить сообщение с задержкой (через несколько секунд)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно что бы бот отправил пользователю сообщение с задержкой, например через 10 секунд после нажатия кнопки, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос подоспел вовремя:

```
import schedule
from threading import Thread
def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)
...
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Тевирп')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send,sending)
def sending(message):
   schedule.every(10).seconds.do(sch,message).tag(message.chat.id)
def sch(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Отправил сообщение через 10 сек')
    schedule.clear(message.chat.id)



if __name__ == "__main__":

    scheduleThread = Thread(target=schedule_checker)
    scheduleThread.daemon = True
    scheduleThread.start()
    bot.polling(none_stop=False,interval=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
```

Используйте самый простой `sleep()` при обработке нажатия кнопки.

Comment: В таком случае остановится весь бот и другим юзерам не нажимавшим на эту кнопку тоже придется подождать, а мне нужно что бы бот "спал" только для юзера нажавшего на кнопку

Comment: @Garison Ну так это же синхронный бот. Чтобы сделать что-то что нужно тебе требуется асинхронный. Aiogram к вашим услугам, Сэр.